# Ms Access - Run Macro from batch file when Other Ms Access Application are running

Tags: ms-access, batch-file

I am calling a Ms Access Macro from a batch file and it is working properly when no other MS Access Application are open. When others are already running when i call the batch file the Application is opened but the macro is not called.

The problem seems to be that all the Ms Access processes have the same name and that the command doesn't know which one to use to launch the macro.

My setup : Windows 7, Office16.

ExecuteMyMacro.Bat :

```
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\BD\MyApplication_FrontEnd.accdb" /x MyMacro
```

How can i change my batch file to work properly even if an other Ms Access Application is already running?

Thanks

---

SOLVED

To solve this problem i added a title and used the internal "msaccess" command to open my macro.

ExecuteMyMacro.Bat:

```
START "CallMyMacro" msaccess "C:\BD\MyApplication_FrontEnd.accdb" /x MyMacro
```

Hope it help someone else.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You may want to report it and get support from Microsoft.

Comment: It should be `Start "Title" "F:\ull or\relative path\to\my executable.exe" <args>`, In your case, you have missed the `"Title"`, _which can be blank_, i.e. `Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" ...`.